# Access Form Method from another static class

Tags: c#, .net, forms, static

So, I'm pretty much out of clues by now, not even sure if it's possible after all.
I have a Visual C# Form, which gets run by the Program.cs (Standard way - VS did all the setup work of course).

In addition to that, I have a class with a static method in a seperate C# file, just because I like keeping one class in one file.

My form code has a public function:

```
public void print(String text)
{
    rtb_log.appendText("\n" + text);
}
```

At a certain point of time, I'm calling the static function from the other class.

Is it possible, to actually access that print method from my other class? Since it's referring to rtb_log ( a rich text box), it's only availible if instanced, and of course not static. But since static methods can only access static members, I'm a little out of ideas here on how to append some text on my form from another class.

Any help here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But since static methods can only access static members, I'm a little out of ideas here on how to append some text on my form from another class.

Static members can access instance members - they just need to know which instance to call the method on. So you could write:

```
public static void Foo(OtherForm myOtherForm)
{
    // Do some stuff...
    myOtherForm.Print(); // Case changed to comply with naming conventions
}
```

Then when you *call* the method, you need to supply a reference to the relevant form. Basically *something* has to determine which instance you want to call `Print` on. Work out who has that information, and pass it on from there. I would recommend *against* using a static variable to hold this information. (Global state makes code less reusable, harder to reason about, and harder to test.)

EDIT: Given the comments, it sounds like you want:

```
// Within the form
private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeClass.StaticMethod(this);
}
```

Comment: Of course, but how do I access the the instance of my main form? I guess that would be the question I'm really not quite aware of. Is there some way to access that instance? It's created in the Program.cs 's main method, using the standart (new Form1());

Also, thanks for pointing out my naming convetion mistake and taking my beginner problems seriously :)

Comment: @Klausklapper: Well if `Program` is creating a `new Form1()` then you have a reference to it at that point... but what's calling your static method? To put it another way: if something created *multiple* instances of your form, how would you expect anything to know which one to call the `Print` method on?

Comment: I'm being stupid, of course you're right. Sorry for being so blind. Thank you a lot! [marking your answer right in 1 minute because it won't let me sooner >:C ]

Comment: @Klausklapper: Ah, so it's within the button click? If so, just pass in `this`, assuming you want it to call back to the same form.

Comment: And again, thank you very much for helping me out on such a newcomer topic that fast!

Answer (score 2):

See below

```
class SomeMainClass
{
    private ClassB form = null;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        form = new ClassB();
        form.Show();
        ClassA foo = new ClassA(this);
    }

    // Use an accessor.
    public ClassB Form
    {
        get { return this.form; }
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    private SomeMainClass mainClass = null;

    // Constructor.
    public ClassA(SomeMainClass _mainClass)
    {
        this.mainClass = _mainClass;
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.mainClass.Form.Print("Something to print");
    }
}

class ClassB : Form
{
    // Constructor.
    public ClassB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Print(String text) 
    {     
        rtb_log.appendText("\n" + text); 
    } 
}
```

*Edit: This is a basic methodology in response to your comment. It is not that efficent in terms of resources but does what you want...*

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. You see, my Form (in your case ClassB) get's instanced at the Program.cs's Main Method, the same way as basicly every simple VC# GUI. I don't have a direct instance name. Or at least I don't know how to access it, since Application.Run(new Form1()); doesn't offer me an instance. And even if it did, I wouldn't be able to access it from my Class A, would I?

Comment: This has been edited to do something like what you require. Note, that there are more effiecnt ways to so this - but I am sure this will do for now...